# Plotting Decision Bounday in Octave

Tags: plot, machine-learning, octave

[image: Raw Data Plot]

I am working on a basic Machine Learning problem, trying to predict how much the battery will last according to the time it was charged for. Above is the raw data plot I have.  I've written the code to compute the cost function and the gradient descent step using Logistic Regression. Now I need to plot a decision boundary for my solution. How do I do that in Octave?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your logistic regression function is

```
cost = sigmoid (theta' * X);
```

where `size(theta)=[1 3]`, and `X(1) = 1` (bias). You solved and obtained the final `theta` vector. Then the decision function is `theta(2) * x2 + theta(3) * x3 + theta(1) = 0`

`x2`, and `x3` is your axis of Charged, Battery Time, respectively

You may find this [page](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html) helpful.

Comment: i think it should be cost = sigmoid(X * theta) i.e sigmoid((theta' *X')')

Comment: (theta' * X) or (X * theta), depends on how X and theta are stored. You flip rows and columns, and the formula gets changed accordingly.